# numbered menu out of dictionary<>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to figure out how to `Console.WriteLine` a dictionary that is numbered.

```
CollectionManager shoppers =
     new CollectionManager
     {
         Carts = new List<Inventory>(),
         Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<Inventory>>()
     };
```

And the method I have tried:

```
public static void DisplayShoppers(CollectionManager shoppers)
{          
     List<string> temp =new List<string>();
     temp = shoppers.Dictionary.Keys.ToList();
     for (int i = 0; i < temp.Count; i++)
     {
         Console.WriteLine((i + 1) + ". Name: " + temp[i]);
     }

     Console.WriteLine("Pick a card to Shopper: ");
     int index = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     if (index > temp.Count || index < 1)
     {
         return ;
     }

     temp.RemoveAt(index - 1);
}
```

It kind of works? but it is only printing the first letter of each entry in the dictionary.

```
switch (choice)
{
    case 1:
        Customers temp = CreateCustomers();
        shoppers.Dictionary.Add(temp.ToString(), new List<Inventory>());
        break;
    case 2:
        DisplayShoppers(shoppers);
        break;
}

//method for creating customer 
static Customers CreateCustomers()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Create a Customer.");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    return new Customers {Name = name};
}
```

Comment: The code displaying the items (from the `temp` variable) seems to be ok (it should display the whole string saved as key). It suggests that the keys of the dictionary may be just single characters. Please verify the code that adds items to the dictionary.

Comment: Can you show us code for adding values to dictionary?

Comment: Added method and method call.

Comment: In the code, `temp.ToString()` method is called to create a key that is later written in the console window. Variable `temp` is of `Customers` type, so verify that `ToString()` method in the `Customers` class returns appropriate string.

Comment: The customer class has an override tostring that returns the name

Comment: The code seems correct in terms of displaying the full customer name in the console. Please try to debug the application and verify that on this line `Console.WriteLine((i + 1) + ". Name: " + temp[i]);` the `temp` collection contains the full names of customers.

Comment: okay it is printing out the whole name for each entry in the dictionary, but im not sure how to take the index-1 and remove it from the dictionary. `shoppers.Dictionary.Remove(index-1);`

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be correct in terms of displaying full customer names in the console.

According to the conversation in comments, if You want to remove selected `Customer` from the Shoppers collection, You can change the line:

`temp.RemoveAt (index-1);`

into

`shoppers.Dictionary.Remove(shoppers.Dictionary.ElementAt (index-1).Key);`

This solution, however, requires additional search in the `Dictionary` only to find key of the item to remove. Consider keeping mappings between item's index and the item itself or just changing the dictionary to a `List<Customer>`.